I have a series and I cannot find a way to calculate its value
So, I have the series:
$$
S_\infty=\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{4k}}\cdot \frac{(4k-1)!}{(2k+1)!(2k-1)!}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^k}{4k\cdot 2^{4k}}\cdot \binom{4k}{2k+1}}
$$
One way I tried to see this was to separate the positive/negative terms and separately calculate the sums (but I still coudn't find a way to calculate their value):
$$
S_\infty = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{8k\cdot 2^{8k}}\cdot \binom{8k}{4k+1}} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(8k-4)\cdot 2^{8k-4}}\cdot \binom{8k-4}{4k-1}}
$$
It should converge (I am trying to find a way to solve a certain problem when I encountered these and the problem has an convergent answer).
Thank you!

@nejimban Thank you, but I need a way to compute it without using any complex analysis and with a full proof (I said this because the page you linked is not loading properly for me). Also, what is the function $F_1$ you used (I know it is called hypergeometric function, but I can't wrap my head around it - as I said, no experience with complex analysis)

I get a different value, specificaly: $S_\infty = -\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}$.

@zetko. You have the exact value

@Anonymous001 Apologies, I made a mistake copying your formula into Mathematica. The sum may be written in terms of Gauss' hypergeometric function, which has special values. But in this case it is simple enough to use the generating function of Catalan numbers directly, as indicated in Claude's answer.

Hint
Using Catalan numbers $$a_k= \frac{(4k-1)!}{(2k+1)!\,(2k-1)!}=\frac{1}{2}\,C_{2 k}$$ which have the generating function
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-16x}}}$$ This  would give much simpler than any hypergeometric functions.

I've tried making use of Catalan numbers (and the generator function), but I can't find a way to use this information along with the $\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{4k}}$ factor
